# MacOS: Identify between NSMenuItem shortcut typed or mouse pressed

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, uikit, nsmenuitem

I have Spritekit game for the Mac. It includes NSMenuItems in the menu as with normal Mac applications. Now the thing is that

- if I choose an action from the menu with the mouse, the Spritekit game starts executing right away and some of the subsequent animation is missed.
- if I choose the same action with the keyboard shortcut, the game starts executing right away but none of the animation is missed since there is no delay switching from menu animation to game animation.

Is there some way to identify if the IBAction sent by the menu item is being triggered by the keyboard equivalent or by mouse? I want to add a start delay to the game animation if mouse is used and no delay for key equivalent.

Comment: Can you explain what "animation is missed" means? Does it help to slightly delay the action after activation, e.g. by 300ms?

Comment: @mschmidt, it does. I'm delaying currently by 400ms and its fine. The problem is that due to this, with keyboard equivalent there is an unnecessary delay that is not optimal for the user experience. I would only want the short delay for mouse activation and no delay for keyboard equivalent. As far as I see they both end up in the same IBAction without me being able to tell the difference which one activated the function.

Comment: Ah, OK. It may be possible, that activation via the keyboard/mouse trigger different callbacks. Have you tested whether `optional func menuNeedsUpdate(_ menu: NSMenu)` of `NSMenuDelegate` is triggered in both cases? It seems unnecessary for keyboard since the menu won't be visible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The type of the current event can be obtained by reading `NSApp.currentEvent.type`.

See [NSApp.currentEvent](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsapplication/1428668-currentevent) and [NSEvent.type](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsevent/1528439-type) for details.

Comment: This one seems to do the trick! I'll add this check to the IBAction.